# Getting socket.io namespace from anywhere in the project

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

After my REST call and some database inserts I want to emit a new notification to the frontend via socket.io like this:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('send notification', notification);
```

Since the function I'm doing this in was triggered via REST and not via socket.io I don't have the variable 'socket'.

I thought at first I can just get 'io' like:

```
var io = require('socket.io') // or like: require('socket.io')(3000)
```

from here I thought I can get the namespace like:

```
var nsp = io.of('/notification-list');
nsp.on('connection', function (socket) { ... }
```

But io seems to be undefined (or if I use it with port 3000 I get EADDRINUSE, because obviously socket.io is connected to `127.0.0.1:3000`

This might be a very silly question, but since I can't figure it out on my own: How can I get the `socket` ready to use in this function? Any help would be much appreciated!

---

**edit:**

I tried friend00's solution, but I still can't figure out on how to do this.

in my `server.js` I create the server & import my socketIO stuff like this:

```
var server =
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
});
require('./socketio_listener/socketIoListener')(server);
```

then my `socketIoListener.js`

```
var sockio = require("socket.io");
var io;

function initIO(server) {
    if (!server) { throw new Error("ERR"); }
    if (!io) {
        io = sockio.listen(server);
    }
    return io;
 }

module.exports.getIO = function () {
    if (!io) {  throw new Error("ERR"); }
    return io;
};

module.exports = function (server) {
io = initIO(server);

var nspNotification = io.of('/notification-list');
nspNotification.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('get notificationList', function (data) {
        notification.findNotifications(socket, data);
    });
    // ...
});
```

now I tried in the function I wanted to emit something via socket.io:

```
var io = require("socket.io").getIO();
```

I also tried:

```
var ioServer = require('../socketio_listener/socketIoListener');
ioServer.getIO();
```

But I still always get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

---

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution, although I'm not quite sure why it was a problem before: I moved `module.exports.getIO = function ()` to the bottom and now it works just fine. Although I thought the placement within the `socketIoListener.js` didn't matter it appearently did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to share the single server-side `io` variable to your other modules via some combination of export or module method calls.

Once you have the socket.io listener initialized like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

You will need to share specific `io` instance with other modules that want to use `socket.io`.  How exactly you share it depends upon the structure of your code and where you're trying to share it to.

---

For example, you could have a module that just managed the initialization of io:

```
var sockio = require("socket.io");
var io;

// mysocketio.js
// constructor function - should only be called once and passed the http server
module.exports = function(server) {
    if (!server) {
        throw new Error("Must pass http server instance to mysocketio module constructor");
    }
    if (!io) {
        io = sockio.listen(server);
    }
    return io;
};

module.exports.getIO = function() {
    if (!io) {
        throw new Error("Must call constructor of mysocketio module before getIO()");
    }
    return io;
};
```

Then, in the one place you initialize it up with a specific http server, you could do this:

```
var io = require("mysocketio")(server);
```

In the other modules where you just want to use the "already initialized" io, you could do this:

```
var io = require("mysocketio").getIO();
```

Comment: I tried your solution and added it to the topic, unfortunately it didn't work for me. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Markus - You need the path to your own module in this: `var io = require("path to your module").getIO();`.  My answer had a typo there which I have now fixed.  FYI, relative paths are tricky to get right for node modules.  So, you will need to make sure all modules are being found properly.  Also, I wonder why you took the useful Error messages out and replaced them with just ERR.  That won't tell someone using this what they did wrong or where the error even came from.

Comment: I just shortened it for the reply, in my code I still have the error message.
as for `var io = require("path to your module").getIO();`: `var ioServer = require('../socketio_listener/socketIoListener');
ioServer.getIO();` should do exactly that. At least that's how I usually import stuff from other files. The path is correct, I just double checked it. Anything else I could be missing?

Comment: @Markus - ahh, I see an issue.   You have to move the assignment to `module.exports = function() {...}` BEFORE `module.exports.getIO = function() {...}` because the constructor assignment replaces the entire module.exports object which kills the getIO assignment if you did that one first.  See my code for the proper order.

Comment: just found this out myself and was wondering why it now works, thanks for the clarification & for you help!